# Слова "сень" и "тень"

Tags: этимология

Эти слова похожи по звучанию и часто употребляются в схожих значениях: "под сенью деревьев" - "под тенью деревьев". Это совпадение или слова действительно имеют общее происхождение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Родственность можно исключить сразу, Т в С (и наоборот) никак и никогда не переходит. 
Я даже не знаю, можно ли назвать "совпадением", мало ли в русском похожих и даже рифмующихся слов.

Значение, кстати, тоже совсем не близкое.
"Тень" - от тьма, "сень" здесь - защита, покровительство.

Хотя вот Фасмер приводит ряд значений в родственных языках, связанных с тенью. Мне трудно что-либо тут комментировать, возможно тут-то как раз совпадения, потому что, как уже сказал, переход Т<C или обратный в русском невозможен.

Ближайшая этимология: род. п. -и ж., сюда же сеґни мн., укр. сiґни мн., блр. сеґнцы (мн.) -- то же, др.-русск. сkни мн., ст.-слав. сkнЮ skiЈ, skТtoj (Клоц., Остром., Супр.), skhn» (Супр.), болг. сяґнка "тень; привидение", сербохорв. сjе?н, род. п. -а м. "тень", словен. sе·?nса -- то же, др.-чеш. sien? ж. "передняя, зал", чеш. siґn№ "зал", слвц. sien№ (ж.) -- то же, польск. sienґ -- то же, в.-луж., н.-луж. senґ "тень". Др. ступень чередования гласных представлена в болг. осоґе, сербохорв. o°соjе "тенистое место", словен. оsо?jе. Далее связано с сияґть.

Дальнейшая этимология: Ср. лтш. sejs "тень" (Эндзелин, ZfslPh 16, 113), гот. skeinan "сиять, светить, блестеть", греч. skoiТj "тенистый", skiЈЇ "тень", skhn» "шатер", дор. skaЇnЈЇ -- то же, др.-инд. сhѓуѓґ ж. "тень, блеск, отражение", нов.-перс. sѓуа "тень, защита", алб. hЊ (из *skoiёѓ) "тень" (Розвадовский, Jagicґ-Festschr. 304 и сл.; Перссон 700; Траутман, ВSW 304; Сольмсен, Unters. gr. Lautl. 278; Гофман, Gr. Wb. 318; Шпехт 11 и сл.; Шрадер--Неринг I, 450). Существуют попытки связать сень и тень, стень (см.) (см. Младенов 626; Горяев, ЭС 357), причем допускается участие языкового табу (Шпехт, там же; Хаверс 124).